# spring xd submit sparkapp by job without result output and status always is STARTED(running)

Tags: apache-spark, spring-xd

I has wrote an app of spark,the code is ：

```java
package com.demo;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sdvdxl on 2016/3/14.
 */
public class SparkCalcDemo {
    private static final String HADOOP_URL = "hdfs://10.10.1.110:8020/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[1]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile(HADOOP_URL + "/xd/dataset1/2016/03/14/15/01", 1);
        JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                JSONObject jobj = JSON.parseObject(new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1))));
                list.add(jobj.getString("name"));
                list.add(jobj.getString("random"));
                return list;
            }
        });
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
            public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
            }
        });
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) {
                return a + b;
            }
        });

        counts.foreach(tuple2 ->
                System.out.println(tuple2._1 + " : " + tuple2._2));
    }
}
```

and the pom content is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>kafka-demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-base64</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oschina</id>
            <url>http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenspring</id>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

when I submit through spark submit-shell,it worked well.But when submitted by xd job `job create --name sparkAppDemo --definition "sparkapp --mainClass=com.demo.SparkCalcDemo --appJar=/home/spark/spark-app.jar --master=spark://localhost:7077" --deploy` `job launch sparkAppDemo`, no result output and in the spring-xd admin ui's status is STARTED, it looks something wrong and hang up.

I screenshot two pictures here:
[job status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pOdC.jpg)

[job detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFxPR.jpg)